# Difficulty using babel and jest together

Tags: node.js, jestjs, babeljs

I am trying to use jest and babel together.

### Overview

How can I compile a folder of ES6 files with babel, ignore particular folders (`/__tests__/`) in the build step, and write my tests in ES6 using jest?

### More details

My directory structure looks like this:

```
src
│   a.js
│   b.js
│   c.js
│
└───__tests__
    │   d.js
```

I wish to compile `src` (excluding the test folders) and put the output in `lib`.

Here are the scripts in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel src -d lib",
  "test": "jest --coverage"
}
```

And `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env"
  ]
}
```

I have also installed babel-jest, so jest will correctly run my tests written in ES6.

With the configuration above, running `yarn build` correctly builds into `lib`, but it also includes the `__tests__` folder. `yarn test` works as expected, correctly running ES6.

I tried:

---

#### 1.

ignoring the `__tests__` folder in `.babelrc`.

Compilation works as expected, no `__tests__` folder:

```
> yarn build
yarn build v0.24.4
$ babel src -d lib
src\a.js -> lib\a.js
src\b.js -> lib\b.js
src\c.js -> lib\c.js
Done in 0.82s.
```

But, `yarn test` no longer works:

```
>yarn test
yarn test v0.24.4
$ jest --coverage
 FAIL  src\__tests__\toccer.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    D:\Dev\toccer\src\__tests__\toccer.js:6
    import toccer from '../'
    ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:290:17)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Apparently the `ignore` option I used above also skips even tranforming the file when jest does its thing.

---

#### 2.

So, I reverted the change above and tried setting the ignore in the CLI for the build script instead.

```
"build": "babel src -d lib --ignore '/__tests__/'"
```

However, the tests folder still gets processed.

```
>yarn build
yarn build v0.24.4
$ babel src -d lib --ignore '/__tests__/'
src\cli.js -> lib\cli.js
src\index.js -> lib\index.js
src\utils.js -> lib\utils.js
src\__tests__\toccer.js -> lib\__tests__\toccer.js
Done in 0.95s.
```

This flag seems to do something different from the ignore option in the configuration file. Actually, it doesn't seem to do anything. I tried `--ignore '/src/a.js'`, and it still processed that file. I saw somewhere that there was a bug with babel in an older version, but should be fixed in the version I am currently using.

#### versions

node: 6.10.0

babel-cli: 6.24.1

babel-jest: 20.0.1

jest-cli: 20.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar setup in a project I'm working on atm. This is the build script I use and everything works file. Building doesn't build test files and `jest` tests written in ES6 get transpiled correctly.

`"dist": "babel src/ -d dist/ --ignore __tests__/*"`

I think you can also do it like this

`"dist": "babel src/ -d dist/ --ignore __mocks__,__tests__"`

I'm also using babel-cli: ^6.24.1.

I figure that `babel` simply doesn't understand the format of the pattern you're using.

Comment: You're right, and this worked! The format was wrong for the ignore flag. Single quotes around the argument messed up the simple example (`--ignore 'src/a.js'` instead of `--ignore src/a.js`). I was referring to some old discussions for that.

I feel like I must have tried `__tests__/*` or `__tests__` without single quotes, but I think I mistakenly left a closing `'` and didn't notice it. Hard to distinguish `'"` from `"`. Doesn't help that babel-cli doesn't seem to throw errors on invalid flags. Just try doing `--not-really-a-flag blah`.

Thanks for the help!